# Python: Writing certain columns specified by user to new file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-writing

If I have a file with multiple columns e.g.

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
a, b, c, d, e, f, g
```

And I would like to write certain columns to a new file, where the column numbers are stored in a list `col=[]`. How would this be done using an iteration of the column numbers stored in a list to replicate the result of, for example:

```
new_file.write(line[0]+','+line[5]+','+line[6]+'\n')
```

I tried:

```
col = [0,5,6]
for line in file:
   new_file.write(line[i] for i in col)
```

However this did not work and I got a type error on the last line. In the end I would like to have the list to be inputted by the user so that the output file contains only the columns specified which are separated with a ',' much like the exaple file above.

Comment: first use the `csv` module, because `for line in file` yields the full line, not the fields like csv would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for line in file:` iterates on each character of each line, not what you want.

As always with comma-separated files, you should use the `csv` module to properly read the fields, and write them back with this same `csv` module:

```
import csv

col = [0,5,6]

with open("input.csv") as fr, open("output.csv","w",newline="") as fw:
    cr = csv.reader(fr)
    cw = csv.writer(fw)
    cw.writerows([row[i] for i in col] for row in cr)
```

creates:

```
0, 5, 6
a, f, g
```

Python 2.7 needs changing `open("output.csv","w",newline="")` by `open("output.csv","wb")`

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the columns first because they came as a single string, also its better to use `str.join` for stick them together:

```
col = [0,5,6]
for line in file:
   line = line.split()
   new_file.write(", ".join(line[i] for i in col))
```